# Minimization problem!

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Im probably not seeing the obvious question but i want to minimize an expression like:

```
Func[A_,B_,θ_,θ1_]:= A Cos[θ-θ1] + B Sin[θ]^2
```

where i do to minimize in order to theta

```
A=1
B=1
θ1=π
NMinimize[Func[A,B,θ,θ1],{θ}]
```

which i can get the desired outputs.
Now if i want to sweep one of the variables (theta1) i can plot it like

```
Plot[NMinimize[
   Func[A, B, θ, θ1], {θ}][[1]], {θ1, -\
π, π}]
```

But now i want to find the minimum of this graphic. I cannot do

```
NMinimize[NMinimize[       Func[A, B, θ, θ1], {θ}][[1]], {θ1}]
```

one thing i can do it to plot several plots for theta1 values and extract the minimum. But is there anyway to do it automatically?

My end goal is to extract the minimums of the plot of (minimum func in respect of theta) as function of theta1 for several A constants

Comment: `NMinimize[Func[A, B, \[Theta], \[Theta]2], {\[Theta], \[Theta]2}]` gives `{-1., {\[Theta] -> 5.05573*10^-21, \[Theta]2 -> -3.14159}}`.

Comment: Alx its is not a same thing! You are optimizing the NMinimize using 2 variables. I just want to fix one and do the optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this similar to what you want?

```
Clear[func, min]
func[a_, b_, theta_, theta1_] := a Cos[theta - theta1] + b Sin[theta]^2

min[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, theta1_?NumericQ] :=
  NArgMin[func[a, b, theta, theta1], {theta}]

Plot[
  min[1, 1, theta1], {theta1, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 3
]
```

[image: plot]

In the call to `min[a, b, theta1]` inside `Plot`, you can substitute different values for $a$ and $b$ and see how the minimum position varies.

Note that I have also replaced single-letter uppercase variable names with the corresponding lower-case ones, to avoid [conflicts with built in symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/27951).